# PHP Session Variable created by Form Submission not persisting

Tags: php, forms, session-variables

I have Opera 12.15 on XP with cookies enabled running on XAMPP and localhost. There is no .htaccess.

1) I can't understand why the following session variable does not persist in Opera whilst it does in the other mainstream browsers. With Opera only, if you revisit the page (via a link) after the Form has been accepted, the session variable has gone and the Form is displayed again. It's okay (i.e. the variable persists) if I just refresh the page.

2) I also have a secondary question, as you can see below I have opened a php tag and started an 'if' statement, then closed the php tag, entered some html, opened a new php tag, closed the 'if' and finally closed the second php tag. Is this valid code, I was originally taught to echo the html within the 'if' and just have one set of php tags? The former is easier and works, I saw it used elsewhere.

Thanks in advance.

```
<?php
// Turn on error reporting
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

session_start();
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">   
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
<title>Opera Session Variable</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
</head>

<body>
<?php
// create a test variable to confirm other session variables outside of Form are   persisting
$_SESSION['test'] = 'Test';

// function to print session variables
function print_array( $_SESSION )
{
echo '<pre>$_SESSION<br />' . "\n";
print_r($_SESSION);
echo "</pre>\n";
}   

// process the submitted form
if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST' ) {
if (isset($_POST['formaccept'])) {
$_SESSION['formaccepted'] = $_POST['formaccept'];
}
}

// print the session variables
print_array( $_SESSION );

// only display the form if it has not previously been accepted in this session
if (!isset($_SESSION['formaccepted'])) {
?>
<p><b>This parargraph should only display if the form has not been accepted in the current session.</b></p>
<br />
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post">
<input type="submit" name="formaccept" value="Accept" />
</form>
<?php
}
?>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Must be the way opera handles the cache, I can't see any error with your code.

As for your second question, that syntax works but is not usually recommended, since it makes the layout dirty being full of snippets.

Comment: Thanks, does that mean I can do something with .htaccess to overcome the problem or is there perhaps an alternative approach, I just don't want the form reappearing in the same session? Surely Opera must have a way of doing this?

Comment: I narrowed this down to Opera versions 11 and 12 and only on XP. No idea why. The session variable does persist using Windows7.

Comment: I think you can file that as a bug to Opera so they can have a look at it, or I'm assuming there's already a newer version out so you don't have to worry about that.

Comment: I did place it on their forums, no response. I have the very latest release so it's not fixed as yet. Cheers.